# problem using Sick LMS200 laser with sicktoolbox

Tags: ros, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am having problem with sick lms200 laser. I am using rs232 protocall for communication. I am having ubuntu 11.04 and ROS electric. I followed the tutorial on

http://www.ros.org/wiki/sicktoolbox_wrapper/Tutorials/UsingTheSicklms

but I just get these two lines and it stays there indefinitely

*** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...

```
 Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB0
```

then I tried to change the sicklms.cc file as suggested in this forum and as given here

http://thebattlegoeson.blogspot.com/2011/06/xyz.html

but still i get the same output no differnce

Its been quite a while I am unable to find the solution it would be of great help if any one can suggest me a suitable solution.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12753/problem-using-sick-lms200-laser-with-sicktoolbox/) by [Puneeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1389/puneeth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Puneeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1389/puneeth/) on 2012-01-26**:
thanks it worked.. :)

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-25**:
Can you try "rosmake --pre-clean sicktoolbox_wrapper" to make sure the wrapper class is also rebuilt against the newer sicktoolbox library you are building.

**Comment by [Puneeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1389/puneeth/) on 2012-01-25**:
/home/mycomp/ros_workspace/sicktoolbox
this is the path I get when i do rosfind. sicktoolbox/build/sicktoolbox-1.0/c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMS.cc  is the path and file i edit. later I go this path in my terminal and do $make all. After that i also do rosmake Sicktoolbox

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-25**:
What path do you get if you do 'rospack find sicktoolbox'? I'd just like to confirm that the file you changed is the driver that ROS is trying to load and was actually recompiled with your changes. A package in /opt/ros will be marked as ROS_NOBUILD and so would be skipped when recompiling.

**Comment by [Puneeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1389/puneeth/) on 2012-01-25**:
I am editing the files in my sicktoolbox package..

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-25**:
Are you editing files in /opt/ros or did you make a development overlay that contains the sicktoolbox package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Eric, thank you. I tried "rosmake --pre-clean sicktoolbox_wrapper" and it worked.

Here is the steps I followed.(In case any one is having trouble)

1. download sicktoolbox

2)rosmake sicktoolbox

3)open this file (your_ros_installation_directory)/ros/diamondback/stacks/sicktoolbox/build/sicktoolbox-1.0/c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMS.cc . Go to line 2317.
3) In this line, add the O_NDELAY flag as shown here:

if((_sick_fd = open(_sick_device_path.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY| O_NDELAY)) < 0) {

throw SickIOException("SickLMS::_setupConnection: - Unable to open serial port");

}

4)After this line, add a system sleep call for 30 seconds. This is required so as to allow the sick laser to start up and start scanning.

sleep(30); // actually It worked fine for me without adding this line as well, but it didn't for my friend

5)go to ros/diamondback/stacks/sicktoolbox/build/sicktoolbox-1.0/c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/

and

$ make all
6)$rosmake sicktoolbax

7)$rosmake sicktoolbox_wrapper

8)rosmake --pre-clean sicktoolbox_wrapper

9. then continue with the tutorials

10)you should see the scan in RVIZ..

once again thank you Eric and all the best for for others.

---

Originally posted by [Puneeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1389/puneeth/) with karma: 56 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Puneeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1389/puneeth/) on 2012-01-26**:
ok will do it..

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-26**:
Could you open a ticket against laser_drivers so that this can be evaluated for adding to the released stacks?